# why the client can't send its second round msg to the server through socket?

Tags: java, socket.io

the first is my client, and second is server side.why the client can't send its second round msg to the server through socket? when you put something in the console, the server will respond through socket, and then send back the msg to client.but when i put something in the console for the second time, the msg cannot be sent to server anymore, please tell me why. thanks

```
package client;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Client {
static Socket sock ;
static InputStreamReader IR;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
InterruptedException 
{
Client client = new Client();
sock = new Socket("localhost", 1112);
IR = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
client.run();
}

public void run() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
    while(true)
    {

    PrintStream PS = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());



    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    System.out.println("Enter your age："); 
    int age = sc.nextInt(); 
    PS.println(age);
    if(age == 0)
  {
    break;
  }
    System.out.println("here");

    BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

    String MSG = BR.readLine();
    System.out.println("client: server has received "+MSG);
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    }
    sock.close();
}



}




package server;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class Server {
static ServerSocket serverSocket;
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, 
InterruptedException {
    Server server = new Server();
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1112);
    server.run();


}

public void run() throws IOException, InterruptedException
{
       while(true)
      {
           //ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1112);
           Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
           InputStreamReader IR = new 
    InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
           BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(IR);

           String msg = BR.readLine();
           System.out.println("server: I have received "+msg);
           Thread.sleep(2000);
           if(msg != null)
           {
               PrintStream PS = new 
PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
               PS.println(msg);
           }else
           {
               break;
           }

    }
       serverSocket.close();
}



}
```

Comment: Don't create the `PrintStream` and the `Scanner` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

So when a client socket attempts to connect to a server socket, it gets put on a queue on the server-side. Then, the `.accept()` method on the server socket takes that request off the queue and "connects" the two sockets.

So, in your code,

1. the client requests connection,
2. the server accepts it,
3. client sends age to server,
4. server reads it and sends it back,
5. client sends another age to the server
6. server never does anything

The problem occurs after step 4 on the server-side. It calls the `.accept()` method again, but there is no client requesting connection so that `.accept()` just waits until it gets a socket requesting connection (it's called a blocking method).

You could fix this problem by moving the `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept()` out of the `while(true)` loop on the server

Comment: thanks a lot , i am new on socket, thank you hahahaha

Comment: @NeilMa yah of course, if it answered your question, go ahead and accept it as the answer please